# Is there a way to make a scrollable interaction for the HoloLens 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, hololens

I'm trying to make a HoloLens 2 app with Unity. The next thing I want to implement is a scrollable list. I would like to scroll just like we all know when e.g. the text is too big for a box in html or something like that.

I know how to move objects but I want them to hide if they are too much out of position, so I can achieve a scrollable list.

Is there any way? I didn't find any tutorials to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented a Virtual Reality "virtual OS" which includes scrollable lists with 3D objects, [as you can see here](https://youtu.be/VQa_mNRa_mw?t=81). If that is your goal as far as display goes, then to achieve this, use `SetActive(false)` on the gameObjects when they're very out of scroll view, and for the exact moment they leave the scroll area -- where they need to be just partially clipped -- you can clip them via an invisible mask cube.

This is the shader for that clipping object (not mine):

```
Shader "Masked/Mask" {
     SubShader {
        // Render the mask after regular geometry, but before masked geometry and
        // transparent things.

        Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry+10" }

        // Don't draw in the RGBA channels; just the depth buffer

        ColorMask 0
        ZWrite On

        // Do nothing specific in the pass:

        Pass {}
    }
}
```

The scrolling event itself is triggered via a collider in the finger tip reacting to a collider in the screen. `OnTrigger`, you would measure speed and translate that for a scroll function. In my case, I'm using a class structure of OS -> App -> Page (including Tabs) -> Widget. This allows you to subclass SomeSpecificWidget (e.g. ImageButton or TextArea) and automatically have it scroll appropriately, without the scroller caring for specifics.